# How to create an array with this sequence '1', '22', '333'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to create an array like `['1', '22', '333']`.
But all I have achieved is an array `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function createArr() {
    let quantity = 3
    let result = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            result.push(i)
        }
    }
    alert(result)
}
```

Comment: Massively unclear what you want here. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to include a proper explanation of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make ['1','22','333'] ?

Comment: I am guessing the question meant to say "I want to **make** an array like ['1', '22', '333'] but **instead my code gives me** [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].  What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: @Amy yes, that is exactly what I wanted to say
sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create an ['1','22','333']

```
function createArr() {
                let quantity = 3
                let result = []
                for (let i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
                    let res;
                    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        res += `${j}`;
                    }
                    result.push(res);
                }
                alert(result)
}
```

Another alternative (Based on @Amy's suggestion)

```
function createArr() {
                let quantity = 3
                let result = []
                for (let i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
                    result.push(i.toString().repeat(i));
                }
                alert(result)
}
```

Comment: Easier, string has a `repeat` function.  So `i.toString().repeat(i)` should achieve similar results, without the concatenation and inner loop.

Comment: I changed ${j} to ${i} and I got what I want
Thank you so much, have a nice day)